# Does Apache Beam need internet to run GCP Dataflow jobs

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, offline, apache-beam, dataflow

I am trying to deploy an Dataflow Job on a GCP VM that will have access to GCP resources but will not have internet access. When I try to run the job I get a connection timeout error, which would make sense if I were trying to connect to the internet. The code breaks because an http connection is being attempted on behalf of apache-beam.

Python Set up:
Before cutting off the VM, I installed all necessary packages using pip and a requirements.txt. This seemed to work because other parts of the code work fine.

The following is the error message I receive when I run the code.

```
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) 
after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(
<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at foo>, 
'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/apache-beam/

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apache-beam==2.9.0 (from versions: )

No matching distribution found for apache-beam==2.9.0
```

I if you are running a python job does it need the to connect to pypi? Is there a hack around this?

Comment: It is a GCP VM, in that case why it does not have internet access?  I am not sure if I understand the situation correctly.

Comment: Your system is installing Apache Beam 2.9.0. That is performed via the Internet. If you have installed a different version of Beam, specify that one.

Comment: @JohnHanley - I have the correct version on beam installed. For some reason it want's to try to reinstall which is problematic because I don't have internet. Is there something in the apache-beam code that tells it to look for updates or patches? If so, can I simply turn it off.

Comment: Apache Beam is just a Python program. Specify the version you have installed in requirements.txt so there is a match.

Comment: Right. Yes the versions match. which is why I don't understand why it is trying to reinstall it. Maybe I should just try to update the package

Comment: You may be able to download the Beam SDK as a tarball, and pass `--sdk_location mybeamtarball.tar`. Could you check if that works?

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you for trying to help and commenting. To get around this issue, I think I am going to use a combination of pubsub and cloud functions. Also, I think if I had written the code in Java, the lack of internet wouldn't be an issue. Based on what I have read, the python SDK needs internet to run apache beam jobs.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR : Copy the Apache Beam SDK Archive into an accessible path and provide the path as a SetupOption sdk_location variable in your Dataflow pipeline.**

I was also struggling for a long time with this setup. Finally I found a solution which does not need internet access while execution.

There are probably multiple ways to do that, but the following two are rather simple.

As a precondition you'll need to create the apache-beam-sdk source archive as following:

1. Clone [Apache Beam GitHub](https://github.com/apache/beam)
2. Switch to required tag eg. `v2.28.0`
3. cd to `beam/sdks/python`
4. Create tar.gz source archive of your required beam_sdk version like following:

   ```
   python setup.py sdist
   ```
5. Now you should have the source archive `apache-beam-2.28.0.tar.gz` in the path `beam/sdks/python/dist/`

**Option 1 - Use Flex templates and copy Apache_Beam_SDK in Dockerfile**
Documentation : [Google Dataflow Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates#python_only_creating_and_building_a_container_image)

1. Create a Dockerfile --> you have to include this `COPY utils/apache-beam-2.28.0.tar.gz /tmp`, because this is going to be the path you can set in your SetupOptions.

```
FROM gcr.io/dataflow-templates-base/python3-template-launcher-base
ARG WORKDIR=/dataflow/template
RUN mkdir -p ${WORKDIR}

WORKDIR ${WORKDIR}

# Due to a change in the Apache Beam base image in version 2.24, you must to install
# libffi-dev manually as a dependency. For more information:
# https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/issues/4891

# update used packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libffi-dev \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


COPY setup.py .
COPY main.py .

COPY path_to_beam_archive/apache-beam-2.28.0.tar.gz /tmp

ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_SETUP_FILE="${WORKDIR}/setup.py"
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_FILE="${WORKDIR}/main.py"

RUN python -m pip install --user --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

2. Set sdk_location to path you've copied the apache_beam_sdk.tar.gz to:

```py
    options.view_as(SetupOptions).sdk_location = '/tmp/apache-beam-2.28.0.tar.gz'
```

3. Build the Docker image with Cloud Build
   `gcloud builds submit --tag $TEMPLATE_IMAGE .`
4. Create a Flex template

```sh
gcloud dataflow flex-template build "gs://define-path-to-your-templates/your-flex-template-name.json" \
 --image=gcr.io/your-project-id/image-name:tag \
 --sdk-language=PYTHON \
 --metadata-file=metadata.json
```

4. Run generated flex-template in your subnetwork (if required)

```sh
gcloud dataflow flex-template run "your-dataflow-job-name" \
--template-file-gcs-location="gs://define-path-to-your-templates/your-flex-template-name.json" \
--parameters staging_location="gs://your-bucket-path/staging/" \
--parameters temp_location="gs://your-bucket-path/temp/" \
--service-account-email="your-restricted-sa-dataflow@your-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
--region="yourRegion" \
--max-workers=6 \
--subnetwork="https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/your-project-id/regions/your-region/subnetworks/your-subnetwork" \
--disable-public-ips
```

**Option 2 - Copy sdk_location from GCS**
According Beam documentation you should be able to even provide directly a GCS / gs:// path for the Option `sdk_location`, but it didn't work for me. But the following should work:

1. Upload previously generated archive to a bucket which you're able to access from your Dataflow Job you'd like to execute. Probably to something like  `gs://yourbucketname/beam_sdks/apache-beam-2.28.0.tar.gz`
2. Copy the apache-beam-sdk in your source code to eg. `/tmp/apache-beam-2.28.0.tar.gz`

```py
# see: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-download-file
from google.cloud import storage

def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
    """Downloads a blob from the bucket."""
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
    # source_blob_name = "storage-object-name"
    # destination_file_name = "local/path/to/file"

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket("gs://your-bucket-name")

    # Construct a client side representation of a blob.
    # Note `Bucket.blob` differs from `Bucket.get_blob` as it doesn't retrieve
    # any content from Google Cloud Storage. As we don't need additional data,
    # using `Bucket.blob` is preferred here.
    blob = bucket.blob("gs://your-bucket-name/path/apache-beam-2.28.0.tar.gz")
    blob.download_to_filename("/tmp/apache-beam-2.28.0.tar.gz")
```

3. Now you can set the sdk_location to the path you've downloaded the sdk archive.

```py
options.view_as(SetupOptions).sdk_location = '/tmp/apache-beam-2.28.0.tar.gz'
```

4. Now your Pipeline should be able to run without internet breakout.

Answer (score 0):

When we use google cloud composer with private ip enabled, we don't have access to internet.

To solve this:

- Create GKE cluster and create a new node pool name "default-pool"(use same name).
- In network tag: add "private".
- In security: Check allow access to all cloud api.

Comment: Hi, can you give more details to this solution?

Comment: Updated the comment @KevinEid

Answer (score 0):

If you run a DataflowPythonOperator in a private Cloud Composer, the job needs to access the internet to download a set of packages from the image `projects/dataflow-service-producer-prod`. But within the private cluster, VMs and GKEs don't have access to the internet.

To solve this problem, you need to create a Cloud NAT and a router: https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/gke-example#step_6_create_a_nat_configuration_using

This will allow your instances to send packets to the internet and receive inbound traffic.