# Apache Beam pipeline failing on GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, apache-beam

I am trying to build and deploy a beam pipeline on GKE, but it keeps failing and gives me this error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apache-beam==2.18.0 (from versions: none)
```

I am using apache/beam_python3.7_sdk from docker hub to build my image, have tried latest, 2.19.0 and 2.18.0. All give the same error.

[GKE log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZouN4.png)

```
2020-03-12T02:31:31.568123538Z 2020-03-12 02:31:31 +0000 [info]: #0 following tail of /var/lib/docker/containers/7b5d36bc9443bc89895895c10604c2ca4b35ebbe13f48b7163078a78f16d8446/7b5d36bc9443bc89895895c10604c2ca4b35ebbe13f48b7163078a78f16d8446-json.log
2020-03-12T02:32:30.071808259Z WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f2c64362310>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/apache-beam/ 
2020-03-12T02:33:30.865490771Z WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f2c643758d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/apache-beam/ 
2020-03-12T02:34:32.151742981Z WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f2c64375350>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/apache-beam/
2020-03-12T02:35:34.443826895Z WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f2c64375a90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/apache-beam/
2020-03-12T02:36:38.736991465Z WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f2c64375c50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/apache-beam/
2020-03-12T02:37:39.017023964Z ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apache-beam==2.18.0 (from versions: none)
2020-03-12T02:37:39.018342794Z ERROR: No matching distribution found for apache-beam==2.18.0
A 2020-03-12T02:37:39.102059327Z /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/dataflow_runner.py:740: BeamDeprecationWarning: BigQuerySink is deprecated since 2.11.0. Use WriteToBigQuery instead.
```

Comment: is there any documentation you have been following whilst setting that up?  the "Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')" looks weird

Comment: no I'm not following a certain documentation, the pipeline itself is very simple, this happens when it fails to recognise apache beam version running, then it attempts to connect to pypi.org, but we are behind a firewall so it can't access and keeps trying and finally displays the error message.

Comment: You can refer to this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56193070/does-apache-beam-need-internet-to-run-gcp-dataflow-jobs